# Image tilt correction in java? OMR Reader Application

Tags: java, image, rotation, graphics2d, tilt

I need to know how to apply tilt correction to scanned images of OMR Sheets. Before reading the sheets for evaluation, the image needs to be aligned  perfectly. How is this done in java? the image files are jpeg files.

One idea I've used is calculating the angle by using tan inverse(opp/adj) ; opp & adj being calculated in pixel units.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -2):

Try aspose.OMR for "com.aspose.omr.imageprocessing.SkewCorrectionAlgorithm" class to perform skew image correction through code.